# Wrong jboss classpath

Tags: jboss, classpath

```
URL imagesUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/images");

the path is /c:/jboss/bin/content/my.war/WEB-INF/classes/images/;
```

which is not found because there is no bin/content folder.

I have my classpath images in WEB-INF/classes folder which jboss cant resolve.
I cant use InputAsStream because this is a folder which makes no sense for a stream.

How to add some resources to classpath?

it works on tomcat.